# Creating 2D wpf custom shapes that are animateable

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, 2d

At present I am working on a project that involves animating a custom built 2D shape in WPF. The shape is to look like a box and at the present I seem to have a few glitches.

Here is what my code looks like at the moment

```
namespace Wpftrial4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        SolidColorBrush fillcolor = new SolidColorBrush();
        SolidColorBrush bordercolor = new SolidColorBrush();


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            fillcolor.Color = Colors.WhiteSmoke;
            bordercolor.Color = Colors.Blue;


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //Manually creating the required 2D Box shape
            Path path_rectangle = new Path();

            path_rectangle.Fill = fillcolor;
            path_rectangle.Stroke = bordercolor;
            path_rectangle.StrokeThickness = 5;

            RectangleGeometry rg = new RectangleGeometry();
            double width_rec = 100; 
            double height_rec = 50;
            double left_rec = 130; 
            double top_rec = 100;
            rg.Rect = new Rect(left_rec, top_rec, width_rec, height_rec);
            path_rectangle.Data = rg;
            canvas1.Children.Add(path_rectangle);


            Path path2_top = new Path();
            path2_top.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown);
            path2_top.StrokeThickness = 6;
            RectangleGeometry rg2 = new RectangleGeometry();
            double width2 = 100;
            double height2 = 2;
            double left2 = 130;
            double top2 = 90;
            rg2.Rect = new Rect(left2, top2, width2, height2);
            path2_top.Data = rg2;
            canvas1.Children.Add(path2_top);


            Path path3_topcover = new Path();
            path3_topcover.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            path3_topcover.StrokeThickness = 5;
            RectangleGeometry rg3 = new RectangleGeometry();
            double width3 = 100;
            double height3 = 5;
            double left3 = 130;
            double top3 = 100;
            rg3.Rect = new Rect(left3, top3, width3, height3);
            path3_topcover.Data = rg3;
            canvas1.Children.Add(path3_topcover);


            //combining part_Group type
            GeometryGroup myGeometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();
            myGeometryGroup.Children.Add(rg);
            myGeometryGroup.Children.Add(rg3);
            Path myPath = new Path();
            myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
            myPath.Data = myGeometryGroup;
            canvas1.Children.Add(myPath);





            ////test animate
            //myCustomAnimatedBox MB2 = new myCustomAnimatedBox(200, 200, 300, 250) { Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 2 };
            //canvas1.Children.Add(MB2); //new myCustomAnimatedBox(200, 200, 300, 250,500,500){Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 2});
            //PointAnimation pa2 = new PointAnimation();
            ////DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            //pa2.To = new Point(100, 100);
            ////da.By = 50;
            //pa2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            ////MB2.BeginAnimation(myCustomAnimatedBox.TopProperty,pa2);//(//MB2.BeginAnimation(myCustomAnimatedBox.CenterProperty, pa2);

        }

        //class- style custom2D shape creation
        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myCustomAnimatedBox MB = new myCustomAnimatedBox(200, 200, 350, 250) { Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 2 };
            canvas1.Children.Add(MB); //new myCustomAnimatedBox(200, 200, 300, 250,500,500){Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 2});
            //PointAnimation pa = new PointAnimation();
            ////DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            //pa.To = new Point(100, 100);
            ////da.By = 50;
            //pa.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            //MB.BeginAnimation(myCustomAnimatedBox.CenterProperty, pa);



        }
    }

    //Class that defines the custom 2D shape
    public class myCustomAnimatedBox : Shape
    {
        private double x1, width;
        private double y1, height;

        private GeometryGroup myBox = new GeometryGroup();


        public myCustomAnimatedBox(double XX1, double YY1, double widTH, double heiGHT)
        {  
            makeBox(XX1, YY1, widTH, heiGHT);

        }



        //public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Center", typeof(Point), typeof(myCustomAnimatedBox),
        //    new PropertyMetadata( null,PropertyChanged));// FrameworkPropertyMetadata( FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
        ////new Point(cent_X, cent_Y)

        //public Point Center
        //{
        //    get { return (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty); }
        //    set 
        //    { 

        //        SetValue(CenterProperty, value);
        //        myBox.Children.Clear();
        //        makeBox(myBox, value.X, value.Y, width, height);
        //    }
        //}

        //public Point Center
        //{
        //    get { return (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty); }
        //    set
        //    {

        //        SetValue(CenterProperty, value);
        //        myBox.Children.Clear();
        //        makeBox(myBox, value.X, value.Y, width, height);
        //    }
        //}
        //public Point Top
        //{
        //    get { return new Point(X1, Y1); }
        //    set 
        //    { 
        //        //X1 = value.X;
        //        //Y1 = value.Y;
        //        Top = value;

        //    }

        //}

        //public static readonly DependencyProperty TopProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Top", typeof(Point), typeof(myCustomAnimatedBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));
            //new PropertyMetadata( null,PropertyChanged));

        public double X1
        {
            get { return x1; }
            set 
            {
                x1 = value;

            }
        }

        public double Y1
        {
            get { return y1; }
            set 
            {
                y1 = value;

            }
        }


        //Trial at creating a dependency property
        //private static void TopPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    myCustomAnimatedBox myB = (myCustomAnimatedBox)d;


        //    myB.InvalidateVisual();



        //}

        protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
        {
            get { return myBox; }
        }

        //Function that draws the object
        private void makeBox(double XX1, double YY1, double widTH, double heiGHT)
        {

            width = widTH;
            height = heiGHT;
            this.X1 = XX1;
            this.Y1 = YY1;
            RectangleGeometry rectangle_part = new RectangleGeometry();
            rectangle_part.Rect = new Rect(X1,Y1,width,height);
            RectangleGeometry rg_cover = new RectangleGeometry();
            RectangleGeometry rg_top = new RectangleGeometry();
            rg_top.Rect = new Rect(X1, Y1 - 10, width, 2);
            rg_cover.Rect = new Rect(X1, Y1, width, 5);
            myBox.Children.Add(rectangle_part);
            myBox.Children.Add(rg_top);
            myBox.Children.Add(rg_cover);


        }


    }
}
```

Since the shape would be undergoing animation like: box opening and closing, I need the custom shape to have  a movable part. GeometryGroup according to most authors seem to offer the most advantages when animation plus other databinding is required however. IN the code I have tested creating the shape manually. This could be seen in code attached to Button1. However when I try to do the class implementation, i am not able to get the kind of effect I want like altering individual constituent characteristics. I am less than 1 month into WPF and would like help in the following areas.

1. Is GeometryGroup ideal for what I want to achieve?
2. will following this course lead to the achievement of my goal. ie will I be able to animate a part of a custom 2D shape built in WPF ie box--open; box---Close.
3. Can someone tell me what I need to do to be able to alter individual properties of the constituent shapes ie rectangles in my custom shape.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

the best choose for doing animated 2d shape is using expression blend software:[Download link software](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc507094.aspx)
and u can see an example tutorial here:[Introduction to Blend: Animation](http://www.kirupa.com/net/intro_blend_animation_pg1.htm)

Comment: Thanks irosg but I get mixed up when it involved building a custom shape as described above that is animateable. More  suggestions?